# navigation stack needs at least one root page - ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, navigation

I try to use `setRoot` of `ionic` nav controller in a function like this:

```
async login(userx: User1){
    // push another page on to the navigation stack
    // causing the nav controller to transition to the new page
    // optional data can also be passed to the pushed page.
    /**/

    if(!userx.email || !userx.password) {
      alert("You need to enter an email and password");
    }
    else if(this.stylist && this.type == 'user') {
      alert("You do not have a stylist account, you can add one using the signup page");
    }
    else if(this.users && this.type == 'stylist') {
      alert("You do not have a user account, you can add one using the signup page");
    }
    else if(!this.users && !this.stylist) {
      alert('You need to select "Hair Stylist" or "User"');
    }
    else {
      this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(userx.email, userx.password).then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        if(data.email && data.uid) {
          if(this.stylist) {
            this.storage.set('type', 'user/stylist/stylist');
            this.storage.set('loggedin', true);
            this.navCtrl.setRoot(FeedStylist);

          }
          else {
            this.storage.set('type', 'user/stylist/user');
            this.storage.set('loggedin', true);
            this.navCtrl.setRoot(FeedUser); 
          }
        }
      }).catch((e) => {alert("The username or password is incorrect")});
    }
  }
```

It works but there is also a popup runtime error that says:

`Uncaught (in promise): navigation stack needs at least one root page`.

I don't understand why it would say this on the very command that I am setting the root. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you use `async` ?

Comment: yah i guess async might not be needed in this situation (that could have been tagged on in some code i was switching around)...its not necessary to say "only you run" because nothing can run until the login is finished anyway? is this just an observation or does it have something to do with the error?

Comment: Your error so strange. Which file do you place these code and where you call it?

Comment: its just in a page...i think it might have to do with the async...since everything functions i found a little hack to disable the error...i plan on going back and seeing if its the async..my guess is the page is getting dismissed before the async function is done...so it is absent the root for a fraction of a second.